# Why my last divison is not being executed?

Tags: c, math, cs50

This is the code for problem 1, cash, of CS50:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <cs50.h>

  int main(void) {
      double d;
      int coins = 0;

      do {
          d = get_float("Change owed: ");
      } while(d < 0);

      for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
          if (d == 0) break;
          if (d >= 0.25) {
              coins += d / 0.25;
              d = fmod(d, 0.25);
              printf("\nd0: %f\n", d);
              printf("coins0: %d\n\n", coins);
          }
          else if (d >= 0.10) {
              coins += d / 0.1;
              d = fmod(d, 0.1);
              printf("\nd1: %f\n", d);
              printf("coins1: %d\n\n", coins);
          }
          else if (d >= 0.05) {
              coins += d / 0.05;
              d = fmod(d, 0.05);
              printf("\nd2: %f\n", d);
              printf("coins2: %d\n\n", coins);
          }
          else if (d >= 0.01) {
              coins += d / 0.01;
              d = fmod(d, 0.01);
              printf("\nd3: %f\n", d);
              printf("coins3: %d\n\n", coins);
          }
      }

      printf("coins: %d\\n\n", coins);
  }
```

When I try to get the total amount of coins that needs at least a penny, the division doesn't occur, so that coins numbers don't get incremented. So, why?

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic has rounding errors. These cause your program not to function as you expect—the decimal numbers you are using are not representable in binary floating-point. Rewrite your program to use only integer arithmetic. Count in integer numbers of cents instead of dollars. If you must get the input as a floating-point number, immediately convert it to an integer by multiplying by 100 and rounding to the nearest integer.

Comment: In the future, when asking a question about why a program does not work, always include sample input, sample observed output, and sample expected output.

Comment: There is no reason to loop through 6 times.  You can change all the "else if" to "if" and get rid of the for statement.  Also, are you trying to determine the total number of coins returned or the total number of each coin type?

Comment: Change `printf("\nd2: %f\n", d);` and others to `printf("\nd2: %.25f\n", d);` to gain insight why code fails.

Comment: Well, I tried what chucx said and 0.01 isn't 0.01, it's 0.009... So I did something that isn't recommended: added 0.01 if the number is == 0.01. But I submitted the version that Eric suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why my last division is not being executed?

As OP [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239334/why-my-last-divison-is-not-being-executed#comment108337235_61239334), `d` was less than 0.01 so `d >= 0.01` is not true.

This is due to floating point vales like 0.05 are [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), not multiples of powers of 10 and not *exactly* 0.05.

---

Instead, avoid accumulated rounding errors with money.  Consider using a integer of the smallest units of money, say 0.01 and of type `long` or `long long`.

Read the float value, scale to cents and round.

```
  // double d;
  long d_cents;
  ...
  do {
      //d = get_float("Change owed: ");
      d_cents= lround(100.0 * get_float("Change owed: "));
  } while(d_cents < 0);
```

Scale math accordingly.

```
      //else if (d >= 0.05) {
      //    coins += d / 0.05;
      //    d = fmod(d, 0.05);
      //    printf("\nd2: %f\n", d);
      //    printf("coins2: %d\n\n", coins);
      //}
      else if (d_cents >= 5) {
          coins += d_cents / 5;
          d_cents %= 5;
          printf("\nd2: %0.2f\n", d_cents/100.0);
          printf("coins2: %d\n\n", coins);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating points may always cause these kind of problems, the solution here is to give your floating numbers a range. For example do not look for if x>0.01 but look for x>(0.01-0.000001)

While using floating points always use ranges, do not ever look for a specific number.